# Pygame window freezes on quit

Tags: python, pygame

I'm relatively new to python and very new to pygame. I'm trying to use pygame. All programs seem to work fine, except when I try to quit. The window freezes ("application not responding") and I have to force quit it. I'm using OSX, python 3.6, and running it through sublime text if that matters. Code is below:

```
import pygame
done = False
size = (400,400)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

while done==False:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.display.quit()
            pygame.quit()
            done = True

pygame.display.quit()
pygame.quit()
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Remove `pygame.display.quit()` and `pygame.quit()` from your event handler and you should be fine.

Answer (score 4):

Try this one, it works for me:

```
import sys
import pygame

size = (400,400)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just do this:

```
import pygame
done = False
size = (400,400)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            quit()
```

this is what i do

Comment: why do you use 'done = False' if you don't use it in the code. And you forgot to break the game loop

Answer (score 0):

or you can use this:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
running = True
width, heigth = 800, 600
size = (width, heigth)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
while running:
    pygame.display.update()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
pygame.quit()
```

don't use pygame.display.quit()